# how to open sidebar tab after user login

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to open sidebar tab after user login sidebar tab open automatically.
sidebar tabs.

```
 <a class="nav-link tablink active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#my-adverts" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">My Adverts</a>
<a class="nav-link tablink default" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#sell-your-car" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Sell my car</a>
<a class="nav-link tablink" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#change-package" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Change Package</a>
```

I open sidebar tab is Sell My Car when user login.
JS code.

```
 function Default() {
      document.getElementsByClassName('defult').click();
 }
```

Comment: Please specify what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to simulate a click on the `<a>` tag? Then probably it does not work, because you have a typo in your className.

Comment: i'm trying when user login sidebar tab Sell My Car by default set

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the problem is in the call for **getElementsByClassName()** function.
The **getElementsByClassName()** function returns an array of elements that have the same class. It does not give just one element. Therefore, the .click() call on return value fails.

---

**How to solve the problem?**

Use **getElementById()** that returns a unique element, instead of **getElementsByClassName()**

---

**Working example:**

**HTML:**

```
 <a id="v-pills-home-tab" 
    class="nav-link tablink active" 
    data-toggle="pill" 
    href="#my-adverts" 
    role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" 
    aria-selected="true">
    My Adverts
 </a>

<a id="v-pills-profile-tab" 
   class="nav-link tablink default" 
   data-toggle="pill" 
   href="#sell-your-car" 
   role="tab" 
   aria-controls="v-pills-profile" 
   aria-selected="false">
   Sell my car
</a>

<a id="v-pills-messages-tab"
   class="nav-link tablink"  
   data-toggle="pill" 
   href="#change-package" 
   role="tab" 
   aria-controls="v-pills-messages" 
   aria-selected="false">
   Change Package
</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function Default() {
      // Click the 'Sell my car' button
      document.getElementsById('v-pills-profile-tab').click();
 }
```

**More information:**

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `a[href=""]` selector:

```
$('a[href="#sell-your-car"]').trigger('click')
```

Example:

```
 function Default() {
  $('a[href="#sell-your-car"]').trigger('click');
 }
```